# Help with Rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rack, carrierwave

I have an uploader, which for the moment includes a Flash uploading option as a fallback. In order to make the flash uploader work I have to use this middleware to preserve the session cookie.

I don't know beans about rack, or middleware, I'm guilt of copying this code from a tutorial on how to fix flash uploading without understanding what it does. Here's the code:

```
require 'rack/utils'

class FlashSessionCookieMiddleware
  def initialize(app, session_key = '_session_id')
    @app = app
    @session_key = session_key
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
      req = Rack::Request.new(env)
      env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = [ @session_key, ::Rack::Utils.escape(req.params[@session_key]) ].join('=').freeze unless req.params[@session_key].nil?
      env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "#{req.params['_http_accept']}".freeze unless req.params['_http_accept'].nil?
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

This gets include in the session store initializer:

```
#initializers/session_store.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(
    Rails.application.config.session_store,
    FlashSessionCookieMiddleware, 
    Rails.application.config.session_options[:key])
```

Now I've run into a problem: I'm setting up an admin namespace to group a bunch of administrator-only controller actions throughout the site. The first thing I tried to do is setup the root of the admin namespace, like so:

```
namespace :admin do
  root :to => 'queues#index'
end
```

But this crashes in the middleware, with the following error message in the server log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin):
  app/uploaders/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
```

So, the middleware (that I don't understand) is trying to call `Admin` (which doesn't exist), I suppose because that's the prefix of the route? I would have been less surprised if it tried to call `AdminController` or `AdminsController`.

This really baffles me because other namespaces in my app work. For instance, this works fine:

```
namespace :account do
  resource :billing, :except => [:edit,:update]
  resource :subscription
end
```

So something about the middleware and defining the root of a namespace is causing this issue, and I don't comprehend it at all to be honest.

If anyone could explain what's going on with this middleware, why it's causing a conflict with my routing, and how to fix it, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda bugged right now because I've had this issue before, and now that I'm trying to reproduce it in a test app, I find that I can't.

But anyway.  The error doesn't have anything to do with the middleware.  It just happens that the wrapping `#call` in the flash middleware is getting stuck with the exception which is happening inside.

I wish I could say what the actual problem is, but it likely has to do with that "Admin" module namespace.  Have you tried say, "Administrator" to see if changing to a different module clears it up?

Rather than `namespace :admin`, you could also use `scope "/admin"`, the latter accomplishing the same thing minus the need to namespace the controller, which will probably solve your problem.

Speaking of, I'm assuming that the 'queues' controller is in a subfolder named "admin", and namespaced `Admin::QueuesController`?

Comment: Ok, with your help I figured it out. I was actually intending to route the root of the admin namespace to an existing, seperate controller action (just QueuesController not Admin::QueuesController) and that doesn't work. I forgot about namespacing automatically prepending all the paths etc. Anyway, you got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh! I wonder I'd that's how to reproduce the problem? Routing both with scope admin, and without to the same controller? Anyway, glad you solved it :-)